# Are JavaScript event handlers removed from browser memory after removing them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

If I've added an event handler...

```
$('button#test').click(function(){

 // some actions

});

<button id="test">click me</button>
```

..and then I remove this button element, will the event handler still be in the browser memory, or it will disappear?

I want to know how many times I can add and remove elements with handlers bound, will this be memory expensive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are removing the elements using jQuery you can be sure that handlers will be detached as well, independently of the browser your code is running in.

> "In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery
>   data associated with the elements are removed. "